# Target.Validation.Type results in "Application-defined or object-defined" error

Tags: excel, excel-2013, validation, vba

I am trying to determine if a cell has data validation using this statement:

```
If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
```

However, I get an error in VBA:

> application-defined or object-defined error

I tried using `On error Resume Next` and `On error Goto 0` but it doesn't help.

How do I check if cell contains data validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. This checks if any cell in the sheet has validation. If it doesn't then it exits the sub. If it has then it checks if the current cell is part of those validation cells

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo Whoa

        If Not Intersect(Target, r) Is Nothing Then
            If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
                '
                '~~> Your code
                '
            End If
        End If
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If your error checking options are "Break on Unhandled Errors" in VBA (Tools, Options, General) then the On Error Resume Next is ignored.